# Phantom missingness in R lm() model

Tags: r, lm

I have a data frame of ~100 observations of 38 demographic variables, as well as pre- and post-test scores in six domains (var1:var6). I fitted a linear model using lm() such that `test.lm <- lm(var1_post ~ var1_pre + dem1 + dem2 + ... + dem38, data=test.df)`. The data frame test.df is a subset of a larger data frame, fulldata.df. In fulldata.df, I have 17 observations that do not have complete post data for var3_post and var4_post. However, test.df does not include those columns. It is just var1_pre, all the demographic variables, and var1_post. There are no missing values at all in test.df.

When I run `summary(test.lm)`, it tells me that 17 observations have been removed for missingness. Presumably the 17 from fulldata?

```
Coefficients: (11 not defined because of singularities)                 
            Estimate    Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
intercept   -2.36E+01   9.84E+00    -2.403  0.02076     *
var1_pre    7.96E+00    1.48E+00    5.368   3.20E-06    ***
dem1        1.90E+00    1.16E+00    1.631   0.11037 
dem2        1.43E-04    1.02E-01    0.001   0.99889 
dem3        -7.52E-01   1.14E+00    -0.66   0.51277 
dem4        7.65E-02    1.65E-01    0.463   0.6459  
...
dem38      -2.50E+00    2.89E+00    -0.866  0.39135


Residual standard error: 3.93 on 42 degrees of freedom                  
  (17 observations deleted due to missingness)                  
Multiple R-squared:  0.6452,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4003                     
F-statistic: 2.634 on 29 and 42 DF,  p-value: 0.002075
```

It doesn't make sense to me at all that lm() would recognize missingness from the larger data frame, but I cannot figure out where else the "missing" 17 observations would be coming from. Even when running `which(!complete.cases(test.df))` it returns `integer(0)`.

Anyone have any thoughts as to where those 17 observations could be or how I might go about identifying them?

Comment: This question is unlikely to receive a useful answer without minimal reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: Show your R command to create `test.df`.

Comment: A helpful diagnostic might be `sapply(test.df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`.

Comment: Also, `summary(test.df)`

Comment: You also have a warning about "11 [coefs] not defined because of singularities".